# Implement a envelope pattern in Marklogic using Xquery?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I want to implement envelope pattern in my json data. My data looks like this

```
{
"id": "1", 
"first_name": "Shawn", 
"last_name": "Grant", 
"email": "sgrant0@51.la", 
"country": "Liberia", 
"ip_address": "37.194.161.124"
}
```

I want to implement envelope pattern like this

```
{
"envelope": { 
 "Code" : "2023"
}, 
"source": {
"id": "1", 
"first_name": "Shawn", 
"last_name": "Grant", 
"email": "sgrant0@51.la", 
"country": "Liberia", 
"ip_address": "37.194.161.124"
}
}
```

I tried the below xquery code but it didnt went well

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
let $doc := fn:collection("transform")
for $i in $doc 
let $object := json:object() --> I am struck here because i dont know how to create a envelope header
let $source := $i
return $source
```

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way JSON nodes map to the XQuery data model in MarkLogic aren't always intuitive if you're used to XML. Generally, working directly with object nodes makes it a little less confusing:

```
for $doc in fn:collection("transform")
let $source := $doc/object-node()
let $envelope := 
  object-node { 
    "Code" : "2023"
  } 
return object-node {
  "envelope" : $envelope,
  "source" : $source
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I like the approach of using json node constructors as described by wst, but sometimes you need to add properties dynamically, which can be complex with those constructors. You can also use `json:object()`, which is a specialization of `map:map()`, or `map:map()` directly, and convert that to json nodes using `xdmp:to-json`:

```
for $doc in fn:collection('transform')
return xdmp:to-json(map:new((
  map:entry("envelope", map:new((
    map:entry("Code", 2023)
  ))),
  map:entry("source", $doc)
)))
```

HTH!